# What is the cardinality of entity relationship between Employee and Department?

Tags: database-design, transaction-log, erd, relations

Recently, a friend of mine asked me this question about the cardinality between  a Department and Employee entities, I replied many to many, then he, my friend, showed me drawings from the internet which says otherwise, one to one. I objected the idea and told him don’t trust everything on the internet. However, after I examined books on Database Concepts I found the one to one relationship that my friend showed to me. As an example I took the following snapshot from “The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Database Management System: **Database Modeling and Design** *4th Edition*”
[image: Snapshot of one to one relationship]

Fortunately, these guys mapped the entities depicting the foreign key relationship. Suppose after a year another employee is assigned to manage a department previously being managed by another employee. At this point are we going to update the mgr_id column and loose the history of the department and employee relationship?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you are referring to one specific scenario or not. There are several possible, which is why you may find a variety on the web. An organisation could allow an employee to work in multiple departments (I do), or a department could have several managers, and an employee might manage multiple departments.

Comment: No I want to understand why almost all books/writers consider one single instance of the case without exceptions

Comment: Possibly because all books base their examples around the same initial scenario. Chen's seminal 1976 paper "The Entity-Relationship Model-Toward a Unified View of Data" gives the Employee Department relationship as part of its running example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the cardinality of **(this)** entity relationship between Employee and Department?

Yes, this relationship ("managed-by") is an example of a one-to-one relationship. This doesn't forbid the two entities form having other relationships, (ie. "works-in") that are of different cardinality, one-to-many or many-to-many.

> Suppose after a year another employee is assigned to manage a department previously being managed by another employee. At this point are we going to update the mgr_id column and loose the history of the department and employee relationship?

Yes, the `department . mgr_id` will be updated and the historical info will be lost. If you want to preserve historical data, the tables should be designed with this in mind. Some DBMS provide built-in support for such temporal data. For some more details, see [Temporal databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database).

Comment: Does that mean such a history is not needed at all ? Or this depends on business rules that are dictated by the client organization ?

Comment: Yes, (depends on business rules), see my edit.

Comment: Ok, this means we are considering only occurrences at a specified time. If we are to ignore updates that may or may not happen in the future like a student changing his/her name, let us leave such a history for the mercy of, as you've said, Temporal data but for updates we know will happen for sure why not we design the database to keep the history. Forexample, I saw as well a one to one relationship for a person marries_to a person. We know people marries to different people for various reasons more commonly, so why shall we ignore such a fact ?

Comment: Simplicity? A temporal database for all information is quite complicated. Almost everything is inserted and never updated or deleted, and every update/delete (in a common database) has to be replaced by an insert.

Comment: I posted this question on a [db forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/13902290#13902290) and I think that said ""slowly changing dimensions" or SCDs is what I was looking for, though may be I didn't express it.